# Copiar un valor de una Tabla mediante un Trigger a otra table

Tags: sqlite, trigger

Estoy creando una app java donde el usuario ingresará un valor y luego salva dicha operacion para que ese valor se registre en una tabla. Lo que necesito es que ese valor por medio un trigger se copie en una tabla la cual no tiene autoincrementar solo una clave principal y que cada vez que un usuario agregue un registro ese registro se copie y "reemplaze"  y sume al valor anterior de la otra tabla.

Para explicarlo mejor:

Tengo una tabla llamada Entradadinero :

Codigo: Integer, Pk Autoinc
pesosentrantes: Double

### ésta tabla sera llenada mediante una interface y por un usuario

Otra tabla llamada "dineroacumulado"

Codigo: Integer: Pk
DineroCantidad: dobule
.......................
Lo que espero mediante un trigger es copiar el valor de pesosentrantes a la tabla dineroacumulado en su campo DineroCantidad y sume al valor ya anterior si es que hubiere un valor. En ésta ultima tabla como notaran no hay un valor autoincremental ya que solo debe haber 1 solo registro (ultima entrada) y ya sumado al anterior.

He buscado en la web algo asi pero no he conseguido como crear un Trigger de estas características. Si alguien puede ayudarme muy agradecido. Excelente foro y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema principal de esta pregunta es que java no tiene tablas, ni triggers. Los que tienen tablas y triggers son las bases de datos, por lo tanto, que base de datos estas usando? y en donde buscaste informacion sobre esa base de datos que no te permitio crear un trigger?

Comment: Sr Ruben. Gracias por su aclaración, se que Java no lo tiene Trigger. Solo Pedi Como hacer un trigger . Tiene razon, omití decir que estoy trabajando en sqlite y el trigger que necesito es para "automatizar" mediante un trigger en un Insert y no escribir codigo extra en java. Para explicarme mejor. Aun estoy en la etapa de diseño de la BD en sqlite y antes de implementarla en mi Java application quiero que ciertas operaciones se Automaticen en la misma BD. Asi me evito escribir mas código cuando diseño mi app. Gracias Muy amable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un posible trigger sería:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_dineroacumulado UPDATE OF pesosentrantes ON Entradadinero 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE dineroacumulado SET DineroCantidad=DineroCantidad + new.pesosentrantes WHERE 1;
  END;
```

**nota** el `WHERE 1` actualiza todas las filas, pero asumimos que `dineroacumulado`solo tiene una fila

edit: ahi caigo que es en un insert prueba este otro

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_dineroacumulado2 AFTER INSERT ON Entradadinero 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE dineroacumulado SET  DineroCantidad= DineroCantidad + 
    NEW.pesosentrantes WHERE 1;
 END;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias alo Malbarez por tu ayuda!

Comment: Alo Malvarez eres Muy Amable  amigo. Muchas Gracias.